# SQLAlchemy - returns different results from query than dbeaver

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, mariadb, dbeaver

I have been running a query using sqlalchemy, and it did not return results. However, I ran the same query in DBeaver, and it did return records.

Code as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy import engine

engine= create_engine(f"mariadb+mariadbconnector://USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER_LOCATION_HERE", pool_pre_ping=True, pool_recycle=40)



engine.execute("""SELECT id, Date1
    FROM example_table
    WHERE Date1 != STR_TO_DATE(Date1, '%Y-%m-%d')""")
```

I'm using MariaDB, and an example of the Date1 format is 2000-01-01 12:00:00-00. Using `STR_TO_DATE(Date1, '%Y-%m-%d')` in DBeaver returns dates in the 2000-01-01 format. Ever record has the same format for Date1.

Is there something I'm missing in sqlalchemy? I've looked through the documentation but I'm not sure what it would be. I am using `'mariadb+mariadbconnector://'` as my connector.

Using `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, the two columns are as follows:

```
`id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`Date1` text DEFAULT NULL,
```

The code above returns no records, but in dbeaver I get records with a date format like 2000-01-01 12:00:00-00.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE example_table`

Comment: @GordThompson I updated it, and Date1 is`text DEFAULT NULL`

Comment: Okay, now create a [mcve] to illustrate your issue and include it in your question. FWIW, [this code](https://gist.github.com/17f1acde143bd4e7718b1f139cad3940) works fine for me.

Comment: `engine.execute()` is deprecated, as is passing a plain text statement to any `.execute()` method. Try doing `from sqlalchemy import text` and then use `.execute(text("SELECT …"))`. (See [my example](https://gist.github.com/17f1acde143bd4e7718b1f139cad3940).)

Comment: The code runs, but it's still returning `None`, even though the records have a format of `2000-01-01 12:00:00-00`.

Comment: What does `show variables like 'date_format'` return?

Comment: Also, do you get results if you use `… WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(Date1) <> 10` instead of `… WHERE Date1 != STR_TO_DATE(Date1, '%Y-%m-%d')` ?

Comment: `show variables like 'date_format' return` returns  `date_format %Y-%m-%d`. Unfortunately I have since run a transformation on that data so now the string length is 10 for all records